# Dynamically creating get request query parameters based on Pydantic schema

Tags: python, fastapi

I know that you can create get requests like this:

```
@router.get("/findStuff")
def get_stuff(a: int = None, b: str = None):
    return {'a': a, 'b': b}
```

But is there a way to create the query parameters dynamically from, let's say, a Pydantic schema? I've tried this below and although it does seem to create the query parameters in the OpenAPI doc, it's unable to process them, returning a 422 (Unprocessable entity). Has anyone tried to do something similar? Being able to specify an object containing the query parameters lets me create get requests dynamically for any arbitrary object with primitive fields. I did this in Flask with webargs, but am not sure what I can do within FastApi.

```
class MySchema(BaseModel):
    a: int = None
    b: str = None

@router.get("/findStuff")
def get_stuff(inputs = Depends(MySchema)):
    return inputs
```

Comment: Your example works as expected here: `/findStuff?a=1` returns `{"a":1,"b":null}`. Do you have a self-contained example that shows the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when I change the ```@router.get("/findStuff")``` to ```@router.get("/findStuff/")``` this behaves as intended. I'll try to move this to something self-contained.

Comment: I realized what caused the 422 error. It was because I specified a different end point right above it that looked like this: ```@router.get("/{id}")
def get_stuff_by_id(id: int):
    return id``` and the "/findStuff" url was interpreted as an improperly specified id. That's why there were no issues when renamed "/findStuff" to "/findStuff/". I was actually able to fix this by just changing the ordering of these methods - by putting the findStuff end point first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was unrealized user error. There was this end point with a path parameter

```
@router.get("/{id}")
def get_stuff_by_id(id: int):
  return id
```

that appeared above the /findStuffs end point, so it got clobbered.

The solution was to just put the /findStuffs block above this block with the path parameter.